# Sf2 split one formType in many form on one page

Tags: forms, validation, symfony

Here is what i would like to achieve. (i thought it would be easier).
I have a UserEntity.
Each field of this entity have an :
 "@Assert\NotNull( groups={"step-1"} )" 
or 
 "@Assert\NotNull( groups={"step-2"} )"

```
/** @ORM\Column(name="username", type="string", length=255, nullable = true)     
* @Assert\NotNull(groups={"step-1"}) 
*/
protected $username;


/** @ORM\Column(name="city", type="string", length=255, nullable = true)     
* @Assert\NotNull( groups={"step-2"} ) 
*/
protected $city;
```

On the formType, i have my 2 fields plus 2 submit buttons :

```
->add('username')
->add('city')
 ->add('submit_form_1', SubmitType::class, array(
            'validation_groups' => 'step-1',
            )
        )
->add('submit_form_2', SubmitType::class, array(
            'validation_groups' => 'step-2',
            )
        )
```

What i would like to do is display the Username inputType,followed by the submitOne button.
Then display the City inputType, followed by the submitTwo button.

Then , when the user click on submit One, validate the datas, and save persist this field in the database.

Here is my view :

```
{{ form_start(form, { 'action': path('fos_user_profile_edit'), 'attr': { 'novalidate' : 'novalidate', 'class': 'fos_user_profile_edit' } }) }}
{{ form_row(form.userType.city) }}
{{ form_widget(form._token) }}
{{ form_widget(form.userType.submit_form_2) }}
{{ form_end(form, {'render_rest': false}) }}

{{ form_start(form, { 'action': path('fos_user_profile_edit'), 'attr': { 'novalidate' : 'novalidate', 'class': 'fos_user_profile_edit' } }) }}
{{ form_row(form.userType.username) }}
{{ form_widget(form._token) }}
{{ form_widget(form.userType.submit_form_1) }}
{{ form_end(form, {'render_rest': false}) }}
```

When i submit the first form everything works great.
When i submit the second one, i've got a "Invalid CSRF token error" and indeed if i look at the dom, only the first form have an input type hidden with the CSRF token.

I did try to input manually the CSRF token (just as a test), and when i submit a form, the datas of this form are persisted, but the the data form the other form are set to null.

I'm kind of stuck right now.
Maybe i'm doing this wrong, the general idea is to split a single entity into differents forms on a same page.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe Symfony will let you render the CSRF token twice on one page for the same form because it will create security vulnerabilities. I believe the best approach here would be to create 2 separate forms that both use the same model. You can remove the groups and leave the constraints on the model or move them to the formType as well.

UsernameType.php

```
$builder
    ->add('username')
    ->add('submit', 
        SubmitType::class, 
        array(
            'constraints' => array(
                new NotNull()
            )
        )
    )
;

public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver
        ->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => userType::class
        ))
    ;
}
```

CityType.php

```
$builder
    ->add('city')
    ->add('submit', 
        SubmitType::class, 
        array(
            'constraints' => array(
                new NotNull()
            )
        )
    )
;

public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver
        ->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => userType::class
        ))
    ;
}
```

Controller:

```
$usernameType = new UsernameType();
$cityType = new CityType();

return array(
    'usernameType' => $usernameType->createView(),
    'cityType' => $cityType->createView()
);
```

Template:

```
{{ form(usernameType) }}
{{ form(cityType) }}
```

Comment: Was this answer helpful at all?